# Is there any valid reason for not using public virtual methods?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

Is there any valid reason for not using public virtual methods?

I have read somewhere that we should avoid using public virtual methods, but I want to confirm from experts if this is valid statement?

Comment: Since a derivation can usurp the access restriction of a virtual method simply by overriding it, I'm genuinely curious what the author of that statement has in mind in making that claim.

Comment: There is, and that is when you don't need them.

Answer (score 8):

For good and stable API design, the Non-Virtual-Interface is a good idiom.

I'm going to defer to the existing good literature on this:

- Herb Sutter: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm
- [More C++ Idioms/Non_Virtual_Interface](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface)

See also these splendid answers:

- [What is the point of a private pure virtual function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970279/what-is-the-point-of-a-private-pure-virtual-function/3970378#3970378)
- [Call a C++ base class method automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107974/call-a-c-base-class-method-automatically/3108006#3108006)
- [Best way to declare an interface in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323595/best-way-to-declare-an-interface-in-c11/14324500#14324500)
- [How to ensure that virtual method calls get propagated all the way to the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273385/how-to-ensure-that-virtual-method-calls-get-propagated-all-the-way-to-the-base-c/1273477#1273477)
- [What's the advantage of this indirect function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663280/whats-the-advantage-of-this-indirect-function-call/663334#663334)

*(Sumant Tambe has an intriguing matrix of [Design Intent Implications](http://cpptruths.blogspot.nl/2007/04/non-virtual-interface-nvi-idiom-and.html) on his blog, which has a few more bits on design intent.)*

Answer (score 7):

Making `virtual` functions non-public allows the base class to create a protocol around them. If nothing else, this could be used for some accounting/profiling requiring instrumentation of only the base class. The base class public interface could be `inline` functions merely forwarding to the `virtual` functions. Sadly the restrictions can be relaxed in derived classes, i.e., a derived class may give public access to a `virtual` function from the base class.

There is actually another important reason for making `virtual` functions `protected`: when overloading `virtual` functions (e.g., the `do_put()` members in `std::num_put<...>`) it is easy to accidentally hide other overloads when overriding just one of the functions. When the `virtual` functions is both the customization point as well as the call interface, this can easily lead to surprising behavior. When the `virtual` functions are `protected` it is clear that the call interface and the customization interfaces are actually different and the problem is avoided even when using the derived class directly. The `virtual` functions probably want to be `protected` to allow overriding functions to call the default implementation from the base class. If there is no default implementation, the `virtual` function can also be `private`.

This answer discusses why `virtual` functions shouldn't be `public`. Whether you should have `virtual` functions in the first place is a separate question with a somewhat non-trivial answer.

Comment: +1 for actually taking the time to explain on the spot :). Oh **and** +1 for that last paragraph. well worth the read.

Answer (score 1):

One thing comes to my mind - not using public virtual methods simplifies separating class's interface from implementation. Say, you provide a public method doing something:

```
public:
    virtual void DoSth()
    {
    }
```

After some time a change is introduced, which requires initializing and finalizing the base class before doing something. If you already derived from your class a few classes, you'll have to change their implementations. But if you've written it in the following way:

```
protected:
    virtual void InternalDoSth()
    {
    }

public:
    void DoSth()
    {
        InternalDoSth();
    }
```

It will be only a matter of changing DoSth's implementation:

```
public:
    void DoSth()
    {
        InitializeSth();
        InternalDoSth();
        FinalizeSth();
    }
```

Creating two-level virtual functions is very cheap and provides you with an additional layer, which allows you easily controlling the way virtual method is called in the future.